# How can I calculate the parameter function of this curved like 3d mesh?

Tags: fitting, mesh, parameters

```
polygons={{{31,1831,76},{20,1780,91},{29,1832,77}},{{-85,1093,-27},{-83,1050,-41},{-83,1050,-43}},{{95,648,22},{78,689,-4},{96,649,23}},{{111,468,138},{115,518,112},{109,469,139}},{{12,2255,-110},{-7,2312,-127},{13,2255,-111}},{{31,1832,80},{37,1885,62},{29,1832,80}},{{-83,1050,-41},{-80,1007,-53},{-78,1007,-54}},{{-38,884,-74},{-54,925,-73},{-36,885,-73}},{{22,1779,90},{33,1831,77},{24,1779,91}},{{-17,844,-72},{5,804,-62},{-18,843,-71}},{{-89,1093,-27},{-87,1049,-41},{-89,1092,-25}},{{45,301,186},{12,237,187},{11,237,189}},{{-36,885,-71},{-56,924,-70},{-38,884,-70}},{{96,649,23},{77,690,-2},{95,650,25}},{{4,1676,105},{-3,1625,108},{-4,1625,107}},{{-22,1523,105},{-32,1473,96},{-30,1472,97}},{{-38,884,-74},{-18,843,-71},{-39,883,-74}},{{-22,168,184},{-62,98,171},{-61,98,169}},{{-29,1472,96},{-48,1373,75},{-46,1373,74}},{{49,2042,-6},{49,1990,18},{51,2043,-6}},{{46,2095,-36},{39,2147,-64},{46,2094,-37}},{{50,2041,-9},{47,1989,15},{48,2041,-8}},{{37,1884,60},{31,1831,76},{29,1832,77}},{{-13,1574,105},{-6,1625,108},{-4,1625,107}},{{47,1936,39},{51,1989,17},{47,1937,41}},{{-74,1228,28},{-68,1276,44},{-76,1229,28}},{{93,647,23},{74,688,-2},{75,688,-4}},{{113,563,83},{115,516,109},{114,517,111}},{{-64,100,167},{-23,169,182},{-62,99,167}},{{46,300,188},{14,236,191},{48,299,188}},{{-29,1472,96},{-22,1523,105},{-30,1472,97}},{{-8,2312,-126},{12,2256,-108},{-8,2312,-124}},{{96,414,157},{98,415,159},{76,358,176}},{{98,415,159},{111,468,138},{97,416,161}},{{110,607,52},{95,650,25},{109,608,54}},{{95,650,25},{76,690,-1},{93,650,26}},{{4,1676,105},{14,1727,100},{6,1676,106}},{{-26,170,184},{-64,99,171},{-25,169,185}},{{78,689,-4},{56,729,-26},{77,690,-2}},{{22,1779,90},{14,1727,100},{12,1727,99}},{{40,1883,60},{47,1937,41},{41,1884,62}},{{45,1936,38},{51,1988,15},{47,1936,39}},{{-5,2313,-127},{16,2257,-109},{15,2256,-111}},{{43,1936,39},{47,1989,17},{47,1989,15}},{{14,1727,102},{23,1780,94},{12,1728,103}},{{20,1780,91},{10,1728,103},{21,1780,93}},{{-46,1373,74},{-57,1324,61},{-55,1324,60}},{{12,1728,103},{3,1677,108},{5,1676,109}},{{-68,1277,42},{-66,1277,41},{-74,1229,24}},{{-81,1007,-56},{-72,965,-64},{-81,1007,-54}},{{-81,1007,-54},{-87,1050,-43},{-81,1007,-56}},{{30,767,-44},{53,727,-26},{54,729,-25}},{{53,727,-26},{75,688,-4},{74,688,-2}},{{93,650,26},{106,607,53},{107,608,54}},{{108,467,135},{114,517,111},{115,516,109}},{{14,236,187},{-22,168,184},{-23,169,182}},{{94,415,157},{72,360,176},{94,416,159}},{{94,415,157},{75,358,174},{73,359,174}},{{-23,1523,104},{-24,1524,102},{-32,1473,94}},{{12,1727,99},{3,1676,106},{10,1728,100}},{{73,359,174},{47,299,185},{46,300,185}},{{46,2094,-37},{41,2147,-65},{47,2093,-39}},{{5,805,-60},{5,804,-62},{29,765,-47}},{{-74,1229,24},{-79,1182,8},{-81,1183,7}},{{50,2041,-9},{49,2094,-38},{52,2041,-9}},{{118,517,110},{117,564,83},{118,518,112}},{{31,766,-48},{8,806,-62},{33,767,-47}},{{-36,885,-73},{-54,925,-70},{-36,885,-71}},{{-38,884,-74},{-15,845,-71},{-17,844,-72}},{{48,2095,-35},{49,2042,-6},{51,2043,-6}},{{-72,1229,25},{-79,1182,10},{-79,1182,8}},{{-31,1473,93},{-20,1523,101},{-29,1473,94}},{{-57,1325,57},{-64,1276,42},{-66,1277,41}},{{41,2147,-65},{31,2201,-89},{43,2147,-65}},{{43,2147,-65},{50,2095,-36},{49,2094,-38}},{{50,2041,-9},{51,1988,15},{49,1988,14}},{{13,2255,-111},{-5,2313,-127},{15,2256,-111}},{{39,2148,-62},{30,2202,-86},{28,2202,-86}},{{43,1937,41},{49,1990,18},{47,1989,17}},{{45,1936,38},{47,1989,15},{49,1988,14}},{{33,1832,79},{23,1780,94},{24,1780,93}},{{-11,1573,108},{-4,1625,111},{-13,1574,109}},{{-2,1625,110},{5,1676,109},{-4,1625,111}},{{-58,923,-71},{-72,965,-67},{-57,924,-73}},{{-85,1092,-25},{-85,1049,-40},{-83,1050,-41}},{{-80,1008,-57},{-72,965,-67},{-81,1007,-56}},{{32,768,-45},{54,729,-25},{56,729,-26}},{{-15,845,-69},{6,806,-59},{8,807,-60}},{{74,688,-2},{54,729,-25},{53,727,-26}},{{92,648,24},{76,690,-1},{74,688,-2}},{{92,648,24},{107,606,51},{106,607,53}},{{72,360,176},{46,300,185},{45,301,186}},{{14,1727,102},{5,1676,109},{6,1676,108}},{{48,299,188},{74,360,177},{46,300,188}},{{114,562,81},{106,607,53},{107,606,51}},{{7,805,-63},{29,765,-47},{5,804,-62}},{{-5,2313,-125},{14,2257,-107},{16,2257,-109}},{{95,648,22},{107,606,51},{93,647,23}},{{76,359,177},{48,299,186},{76,358,176}},{{-23,169,182},{-61,98,169},{-62,99,167}},{{-25,170,182},{-65,100,169},{-26,170,184}},{{-70,966,-67},{-57,924,-73},{-72,965,-67}},{{-81,1183,7},{-85,1093,-27},{-87,1094,-28}},{{32,2202,-87},{14,2257,-107},{30,2202,-86}},{{29,1832,77},{20,1780,91},{29,1832,80}},{{-32,1473,96},{-48,1373,75},{-30,1472,97}},{{33,767,-47},{8,807,-60},{32,768,-45}},{{52,2041,-9},{50,2095,-36},{52,2042,-7}},{{-65,100,169},{-62,99,167},{-62,98,171}},{{-48,1374,71},{-55,1325,58},{-57,1325,57}},{{-62,98,171},{-25,169,185},{-64,99,171}},{{11,237,189},{-25,170,182},{-26,170,184}},{{98,415,159},{76,359,177},{76,358,176}},{{46,300,185},{14,236,187},{12,237,187}},{{112,467,137},{118,518,112},{111,468,138}},{{8,806,-62},{-15,845,-69},{8,807,-60}},{{109,606,51},{96,649,23},{110,607,52}},{{117,563,82},{109,608,54},{117,564,83}},{{116,562,80},{110,607,52},{117,563,82}},{{117,516,109},{117,563,82},{118,517,110}},{{110,467,135},{118,517,110},{112,467,137}},{{55,727,-29},{33,767,-47},{56,729,-28}},{{-36,885,-73},{-15,845,-69},{-15,845,-71}},{{77,688,-5},{56,729,-28},{78,689,-4}},{{7,805,-63},{-15,845,-71},{8,806,-62}},{{-87,1092,-24},{-82,1182,10},{-89,1092,-25}},{{-68,966,-66},{-54,925,-70},{-54,925,-73}},{{-70,966,-67},{-54,925,-73},{-56,924,-74}},{{-82,1183,8},{-89,1092,-25},{-82,1182,10}},{{-78,1008,-56},{-68,966,-64},{-68,966,-66}},{{-83,1050,-43},{-78,1007,-54},{-78,1008,-56}},{{-66,1277,41},{-72,1229,25},{-74,1229,24}},{{-64,1276,42},{-72,1228,27},{-72,1229,25}},{{-13,1574,105},{-20,1523,101},{-22,1523,100}},{{24,1779,91},{14,1727,102},{14,1727,100}},{{52,2041,-9},{51,1989,17},{51,1988,15}},{{38,1883,59},{33,1831,77},{31,1831,76}},{{41,2147,-65},{49,2094,-38},{47,2093,-39}},{{43,2147,-65},{32,2202,-87},{43,2148,-63}},{{48,2041,-8},{46,2095,-36},{46,2094,-37}},{{31,2201,-89},{16,2257,-109},{32,2202,-87}},{{45,1936,38},{40,1883,60},{38,1883,59}},{{29,2200,-90},{15,2256,-111},{31,2201,-89}},{{12,2255,-110},{13,2255,-111},{29,2200,-90}},{{-6,2313,-123},{12,2256,-108},{14,2257,-107}},{{-5,2313,-125},{-5,2313,-127},{-7,2312,-127}},{{28,2202,-86},{14,2257,-107},{12,2256,-108}},{{12,2256,-108},{28,2201,-88},{28,2202,-86}},{{-4,1625,107},{-11,1574,106},{-13,1574,105}},{{48,2095,-35},{39,2148,-62},{46,2095,-36}},{{52,2042,-7},{49,1990,18},{51,1989,17}},{{38,1883,59},{43,1936,39},{45,1936,38}},{{47,1989,17},{48,2041,-8},{47,1989,15}},{{47,1937,41},{49,1990,18},{45,1937,42}},{{3,1676,106},{-4,1625,107},{-6,1625,108}},{{21,1780,93},{12,1728,103},{23,1780,94}},{{43,1937,41},{37,1884,60},{37,1885,62}},{{21,1780,93},{31,1832,80},{29,1832,80}},{{41,1884,62},{45,1937,42},{39,1885,63}},{{39,1885,63},{43,1937,41},{37,1885,62}},{{-4,1625,111},{3,1677,108},{-6,1625,110}},{{-11,1573,108},{-22,1523,105},{-20,1523,103}},{{12,1727,99},{20,1780,91},{22,1779,90}},{{-15,1574,108},{-22,1523,105},{-13,1574,109}},{{33,1831,77},{33,1832,79},{24,1779,91}},{{-13,1574,105},{-24,1524,102},{-15,1574,106}},{{-87,1094,-28},{-82,1183,8},{-81,1183,7}},{{-50,1374,74},{-57,1324,61},{-48,1373,75}},{{-66,1276,45},{-59,1325,60},{-68,1276,44}},{{-6,1625,110},{-13,1574,109},{-4,1625,111}},{{-68,1277,42},{-76,1229,28},{-68,1276,44}},{{-82,1182,10},{-76,1229,25},{-82,1183,8}},{{-76,1229,28},{-81,1181,11},{-74,1228,28}},{{-39,883,-74},{-58,923,-71},{-57,924,-73}},{{-78,1007,-54},{-70,965,-63},{-68,966,-64}},{{-87,1050,-43},{-87,1094,-28},{-85,1051,-44}},{{-85,1051,-44},{-81,1007,-56},{-87,1050,-43}},{{-56,924,-70},{-40,883,-71},{-38,884,-70}},{{-66,1277,41},{-59,1325,58},{-57,1325,57}},{{-36,885,-71},{-17,844,-68},{-15,845,-69}},{{-40,883,-71},{-17,844,-68},{-38,884,-70}},{{-64,1276,44},{-57,1324,61},{-66,1276,45}},{{5,804,-62},{-19,843,-69},{-18,843,-71}},{{-56,924,-70},{-72,965,-64},{-58,923,-71}},{{-19,843,-69},{-39,883,-74},{-18,843,-71}},{{55,727,-29},{75,688,-4},{53,727,-28}},{{53,727,-28},{31,766,-48},{55,727,-29}},{{-57,924,-73},{-38,884,-74},{-39,883,-74}},{{5,805,-60},{-17,844,-68},{-19,843,-69}},{{56,729,-26},{76,690,-1},{77,690,-2}},{{-68,966,-64},{-56,924,-70},{-54,925,-70}},{{114,517,111},{115,564,84},{113,563,83}},{{117,564,83},{107,608,54},{115,564,84}},{{6,806,-59},{29,766,-45},{30,767,-44}},{{107,608,54},{113,563,83},{115,564,84}},{{-29,1473,94},{-20,1523,101},{-20,1523,103}},{{118,518,112},{115,564,84},{115,518,112}},{{117,516,109},{114,562,81},{116,562,80}},{{108,468,137},{115,518,112},{114,517,111}},{{-48,1374,71},{-59,1325,58},{-50,1374,72}},{{39,2147,-64},{28,2202,-86},{28,2201,-88}},{{108,468,137},{94,415,157},{94,416,159}},{{97,416,161},{109,469,139},{95,416,161}},{{14,236,191},{-22,168,184},{15,235,189}},{{110,467,135},{115,516,109},{117,516,109}},{{8,807,-60},{30,767,-44},{32,768,-45}},{{45,301,186},{46,300,188},{74,360,177}},{{15,235,189},{48,299,188},{14,236,191}},{{12,237,191},{-23,168,185},{14,236,191}},{{96,414,157},{108,467,135},{110,467,135}},{{-23,169,182},{12,237,187},{14,236,187}},{{-25,169,185},{11,237,189},{-26,170,184}},{{-31,1473,93},{-24,1524,102},{-22,1523,100}},{{76,359,177},{95,416,161},{74,360,177}},{{-50,1374,72},{-31,1473,93},{-48,1374,71}},{{107,606,51},{116,562,80},{114,562,81}},{{33,1832,79},{39,1885,63},{31,1832,80}},{{43,2148,-63},{41,2148,-61},{48,2095,-35}},{{-72,1228,27},{-74,1228,28},{-79,1182,10}},{{-81,1181,11},{-85,1092,-25},{-79,1182,10}},{{-85,1051,-44},{-78,1008,-56},{-80,1008,-57}},{{-80,1007,-53},{-85,1049,-40},{-87,1049,-41}},{{-79,1182,8},{-85,1092,-25},{-85,1093,-27}},{{-31,1473,93},{-46,1373,72},{-48,1374,71}},{{31,1831,76},{22,1779,90},{20,1780,91}},{{-85,1093,-27},{-85,1092,-25},{-83,1050,-41}},{{95,648,22},{77,688,-5},{78,689,-4}},{{111,468,138},{118,518,112},{115,518,112}},{{12,2255,-110},{-8,2312,-126},{-7,2312,-127}},{{31,1832,80},{39,1885,63},{37,1885,62}},{{-83,1050,-41},{-85,1049,-40},{-80,1007,-53}},{{-38,884,-74},{-56,924,-74},{-54,925,-73}},{{22,1779,90},{31,1831,76},{33,1831,77}},{{-17,844,-72},{7,805,-63},{5,804,-62}},{{-89,1093,-27},{-87,1050,-43},{-87,1049,-41}},{{45,301,186},{46,300,185},{12,237,187}},{{-36,885,-71},{-54,925,-70},{-56,924,-70}},{{96,649,23},{78,689,-4},{77,690,-2}},{{4,1676,105},{6,1676,106},{-3,1625,108}},{{-22,1523,105},{-23,1523,104},{-32,1473,96}},{{-38,884,-74},{-17,844,-72},{-18,843,-71}},{{-22,168,184},{-23,168,185},{-62,98,171}},{{-29,1472,96},{-30,1472,97},{-48,1373,75}},{{49,2042,-6},{47,1989,17},{49,1990,18}},{{46,2095,-36},{39,2148,-62},{39,2147,-64}},{{50,2041,-9},{49,1988,14},{47,1989,15}},{{37,1884,60},{38,1883,59},{31,1831,76}},{{-13,1574,105},{-15,1574,106},{-6,1625,108}},{{47,1936,39},{51,1988,15},{51,1989,17}},{{-74,1228,28},{-66,1276,45},{-68,1276,44}},{{93,647,23},{92,648,24},{74,688,-2}},{{113,563,83},{114,562,81},{115,516,109}},{{-64,100,167},{-25,170,182},{-23,169,182}},{{46,300,188},{12,237,191},{14,236,191}},{{-29,1472,96},{-20,1523,103},{-22,1523,105}},{{-8,2312,-126},{12,2255,-110},{12,2256,-108}},{{96,414,157},{110,467,135},{112,467,137}},{{48,299,186},{15,235,189},{47,299,185}},{{15,235,189},{14,236,187},{47,299,185}},{{96,414,157},{112,467,137},{98,415,159}},{{48,299,186},{47,299,185},{76,358,176}},{{47,299,185},{75,358,174},{76,358,176}},{{75,358,174},{96,414,157},{76,358,176}},{{98,415,159},{112,467,137},{111,468,138}},{{110,607,52},{96,649,23},{95,650,25}},{{95,650,25},{77,690,-2},{76,690,-1}},{{93,650,26},{107,608,54},{95,650,25}},{{107,608,54},{109,608,54},{95,650,25}},{{4,1676,105},{12,1727,99},{14,1727,100}},{{-26,170,184},{-65,100,169},{-64,99,171}},{{78,689,-4},{56,729,-28},{56,729,-26}},{{22,1779,90},{24,1779,91},{14,1727,100}},{{40,1883,60},{47,1936,39},{47,1937,41}},{{45,1936,38},{49,1988,14},{51,1988,15}},{{-5,2313,-127},{-5,2313,-125},{16,2257,-109}},{{43,1936,39},{43,1937,41},{47,1989,17}},{{14,1727,102},{24,1780,93},{23,1780,94}},{{20,1780,91},{10,1728,100},{10,1728,103}},{{-46,1373,74},{-48,1373,75},{-57,1324,61}},{{12,1728,103},{10,1728,103},{3,1677,108}},{{-74,1229,24},{-81,1183,7},{-76,1229,25}},{{-81,1183,7},{-82,1183,8},{-76,1229,25}},{{-76,1229,25},{-68,1277,42},{-74,1229,24}},{{-81,1007,-56},{-72,965,-67},{-72,965,-64}},{{-81,1007,-54},{-87,1049,-41},{-87,1050,-43}},{{30,767,-44},{29,766,-45},{53,727,-26}},{{53,727,-26},{53,727,-28},{75,688,-4}},{{93,650,26},{92,648,24},{106,607,53}},{{108,467,135},{108,468,137},{114,517,111}},{{14,236,187},{15,235,189},{-22,168,184}},{{94,415,157},{73,359,174},{72,360,176}},{{94,415,157},{96,414,157},{75,358,174}},{{-59,1325,60},{-50,1374,74},{-50,1374,72}},{{-50,1374,74},{-32,1473,96},{-50,1374,72}},{{-32,1473,96},{-23,1523,104},{-32,1473,94}},{{-23,1523,104},{-15,1574,108},{-24,1524,102}},{{-15,1574,108},{-6,1625,110},{-6,1625,108}},{{-6,1625,110},{3,1677,108},{3,1676,106}},{{-6,1625,108},{-6,1625,110},{3,1676,106}},{{3,1677,108},{10,1728,103},{3,1676,106}},{{10,1728,103},{10,1728,100},{3,1676,106}},{{-68,1277,42},{-68,1276,44},{-59,1325,58}},{{-68,1276,44},{-59,1325,60},{-59,1325,58}},{{-50,1374,72},{-59,1325,58},{-59,1325,60}},{{-15,1574,108},{-6,1625,108},{-15,1574,106}},{{-15,1574,108},{-15,1574,106},{-24,1524,102}},{{-32,1473,94},{-50,1374,72},{-32,1473,96}},{{12,1727,99},{4,1676,105},{3,1676,106}},{{73,359,174},{75,358,174},{47,299,185}},{{50,2041,-9},{48,2041,-8},{46,2094,-37}},{{46,2094,-37},{39,2147,-64},{41,2147,-65}},{{47,2093,-39},{50,2041,-9},{46,2094,-37}},{{29,765,-47},{53,727,-28},{29,766,-45}},{{53,727,-28},{53,727,-26},{29,766,-45}},{{29,766,-45},{5,805,-60},{29,765,-47}},{{-74,1229,24},{-72,1229,25},{-79,1182,8}},{{50,2041,-9},{47,2093,-39},{49,2094,-38}},{{118,517,110},{117,563,82},{117,564,83}},{{31,766,-48},{7,805,-63},{8,806,-62}},{{-36,885,-73},{-54,925,-73},{-54,925,-70}},{{-38,884,-74},{-36,885,-73},{-15,845,-71}},{{48,2095,-35},{46,2095,-36},{49,2042,-6}},{{-72,1229,25},{-72,1228,27},{-79,1182,10}},{{-31,1473,93},{-22,1523,100},{-20,1523,101}},{{-57,1325,57},{-55,1325,58},{-64,1276,42}},{{41,2147,-65},{29,2200,-90},{31,2201,-89}},{{43,2147,-65},{43,2148,-63},{50,2095,-36}},{{50,2041,-9},{52,2041,-9},{51,1988,15}},{{13,2255,-111},{-7,2312,-127},{-5,2313,-127}},{{39,2148,-62},{41,2148,-61},{30,2202,-86}},{{43,1937,41},{45,1937,42},{49,1990,18}},{{45,1936,38},{43,1936,39},{47,1989,15}},{{33,1832,79},{31,1832,80},{23,1780,94}},{{-11,1573,108},{-2,1625,110},{-4,1625,111}},{{-2,1625,110},{6,1676,108},{5,1676,109}},{{-58,923,-71},{-72,965,-64},{-72,965,-67}},{{-85,1092,-25},{-87,1092,-24},{-85,1049,-40}},{{-80,1008,-57},{-70,966,-67},{-72,965,-67}},{{32,768,-45},{30,767,-44},{54,729,-25}},{{-15,845,-69},{-17,844,-68},{6,806,-59}},{{74,688,-2},{76,690,-1},{54,729,-25}},{{92,648,24},{93,650,26},{76,690,-1}},{{92,648,24},{93,647,23},{107,606,51}},{{72,360,176},{73,359,174},{46,300,185}},{{14,1727,102},{12,1728,103},{5,1676,109}},{{48,299,188},{76,359,177},{74,360,177}},{{114,562,81},{113,563,83},{106,607,53}},{{7,805,-63},{31,766,-48},{29,765,-47}},{{-5,2313,-125},{-6,2313,-123},{14,2257,-107}},{{95,648,22},{109,606,51},{107,606,51}},{{93,647,23},{75,688,-4},{95,648,22}},{{75,688,-4},{77,688,-5},{95,648,22}},{{76,359,177},{48,299,188},{48,299,186}},{{-23,169,182},{-22,168,184},{-61,98,169}},{{-25,170,182},{-64,100,167},{-65,100,169}},{{-70,966,-67},{-56,924,-74},{-57,924,-73}},{{-81,1183,7},{-79,1182,8},{-85,1093,-27}},{{41,2148,-61},{43,2148,-63},{30,2202,-86}},{{43,2148,-63},{32,2202,-87},{30,2202,-86}},{{32,2202,-87},{16,2257,-109},{14,2257,-107}},{{20,1780,91},{21,1780,93},{29,1832,80}},{{29,1832,80},{37,1885,62},{29,1832,77}},{{37,1885,62},{37,1884,60},{29,1832,77}},{{-32,1473,96},{-50,1374,74},{-48,1373,75}},{{56,729,-26},{56,729,-28},{32,768,-45}},{{56,729,-28},{33,767,-47},{32,768,-45}},{{33,767,-47},{8,806,-62},{8,807,-60}},{{52,2041,-9},{49,2094,-38},{50,2095,-36}},{{-62,98,171},{-64,99,171},{-65,100,169}},{{-65,100,169},{-64,100,167},{-62,99,167}},{{-62,99,167},{-61,98,169},{-62,98,171}},{{-48,1374,71},{-46,1373,72},{-55,1325,58}},{{-62,98,171},{-23,168,185},{-25,169,185}},{{11,237,189},{12,237,187},{-25,170,182}},{{98,415,159},{97,416,161},{76,359,177}},{{46,300,185},{47,299,185},{14,236,187}},{{112,467,137},{118,517,110},{118,518,112}},{{8,806,-62},{-15,845,-71},{-15,845,-69}},{{109,606,51},{95,648,22},{96,649,23}},{{117,563,82},{110,607,52},{109,608,54}},{{116,562,80},{109,606,51},{110,607,52}},{{117,516,109},{116,562,80},{117,563,82}},{{110,467,135},{117,516,109},{118,517,110}},{{55,727,-29},{31,766,-48},{33,767,-47}},{{-36,885,-73},{-36,885,-71},{-15,845,-69}},{{77,688,-5},{55,727,-29},{56,729,-28}},{{7,805,-63},{-17,844,-72},{-15,845,-71}},{{-87,1092,-24},{-81,1181,11},{-82,1182,10}},{{-68,966,-66},{-68,966,-64},{-54,925,-70}},{{-70,966,-67},{-68,966,-66},{-54,925,-73}},{{-82,1183,8},{-89,1093,-27},{-89,1092,-25}},{{-78,1008,-56},{-78,1007,-54},{-68,966,-64}},{{-83,1050,-43},{-83,1050,-41},{-78,1007,-54}},{{-66,1277,41},{-64,1276,42},{-72,1229,25}},{{-64,1276,42},{-64,1276,44},{-72,1228,27}},{{-13,1574,105},{-11,1574,106},{-20,1523,101}},{{24,1779,91},{24,1780,93},{14,1727,102}},{{52,2041,-9},{52,2042,-7},{51,1989,17}},{{38,1883,59},{40,1883,60},{33,1831,77}},{{41,2147,-65},{43,2147,-65},{49,2094,-38}},{{43,2147,-65},{31,2201,-89},{32,2202,-87}},{{48,2041,-8},{49,2042,-6},{46,2095,-36}},{{31,2201,-89},{15,2256,-111},{16,2257,-109}},{{45,1936,38},{47,1936,39},{40,1883,60}},{{29,2200,-90},{13,2255,-111},{15,2256,-111}},{{29,2200,-90},{41,2147,-65},{28,2201,-88}},{{41,2147,-65},{39,2147,-64},{28,2201,-88}},{{28,2201,-88},{12,2255,-110},{29,2200,-90}},{{-6,2313,-123},{-8,2312,-124},{12,2256,-108}},{{-7,2312,-127},{-8,2312,-126},{-5,2313,-125}},{{-8,2312,-126},{-8,2312,-124},{-6,2313,-123}},{{-5,2313,-125},{-8,2312,-126},{-6,2313,-123}},{{28,2202,-86},{30,2202,-86},{14,2257,-107}},{{12,2256,-108},{12,2255,-110},{28,2201,-88}},{{-4,1625,107},{-3,1625,108},{-11,1574,106}},{{48,2095,-35},{41,2148,-61},{39,2148,-62}},{{52,2042,-7},{51,2043,-6},{49,1990,18}},{{38,1883,59},{37,1884,60},{43,1936,39}},{{47,1989,17},{49,2042,-6},{48,2041,-8}},{{47,1937,41},{51,1989,17},{49,1990,18}},{{3,1676,106},{4,1676,105},{-4,1625,107}},{{21,1780,93},{10,1728,103},{12,1728,103}},{{43,1937,41},{43,1936,39},{37,1884,60}},{{21,1780,93},{23,1780,94},{31,1832,80}},{{41,1884,62},{47,1937,41},{45,1937,42}},{{39,1885,63},{45,1937,42},{43,1937,41}},{{-4,1625,111},{5,1676,109},{3,1677,108}},{{-11,1573,108},{-13,1574,109},{-22,1523,105}},{{12,1727,99},{10,1728,100},{20,1780,91}},{{-15,1574,108},{-23,1523,104},{-22,1523,105}},{{33,1831,77},{40,1883,60},{41,1884,62}},{{41,1884,62},{33,1832,79},{33,1831,77}},{{33,1832,79},{24,1780,93},{24,1779,91}},{{-13,1574,105},{-22,1523,100},{-24,1524,102}},{{-87,1094,-28},{-89,1093,-27},{-82,1183,8}},{{-50,1374,74},{-59,1325,60},{-57,1324,61}},{{-66,1276,45},{-57,1324,61},{-59,1325,60}},{{-6,1625,110},{-15,1574,108},{-13,1574,109}},{{-68,1277,42},{-76,1229,25},{-76,1229,28}},{{-82,1182,10},{-76,1229,28},{-76,1229,25}},{{-76,1229,28},{-82,1182,10},{-81,1181,11}},{{-39,883,-74},{-40,883,-71},{-58,923,-71}},{{-78,1007,-54},{-80,1007,-53},{-70,965,-63}},{{-87,1050,-43},{-89,1093,-27},{-87,1094,-28}},{{-85,1051,-44},{-80,1008,-57},{-81,1007,-56}},{{-56,924,-70},{-58,923,-71},{-40,883,-71}},{{-66,1277,41},{-68,1277,42},{-59,1325,58}},{{-36,885,-71},{-38,884,-70},{-17,844,-68}},{{-40,883,-71},{-19,843,-69},{-17,844,-68}},{{-64,1276,44},{-55,1324,60},{-57,1324,61}},{{5,804,-62},{5,805,-60},{-19,843,-69}},{{-56,924,-70},{-70,965,-63},{-72,965,-64}},{{-19,843,-69},{-40,883,-71},{-39,883,-74}},{{55,727,-29},{77,688,-5},{75,688,-4}},{{53,727,-28},{29,765,-47},{31,766,-48}},{{-57,924,-73},{-56,924,-74},{-38,884,-74}},{{5,805,-60},{6,806,-59},{-17,844,-68}},{{56,729,-26},{54,729,-25},{76,690,-1}},{{-68,966,-64},{-70,965,-63},{-56,924,-70}},{{114,517,111},{115,518,112},{115,564,84}},{{117,564,83},{109,608,54},{107,608,54}},{{6,806,-59},{5,805,-60},{29,766,-45}},{{107,608,54},{106,607,53},{113,563,83}},{{6,1676,106},{14,1727,100},{14,1727,102}},{{14,1727,102},{6,1676,108},{6,1676,106}},{{6,1676,108},{-2,1625,110},{6,1676,106}},{{-2,1625,110},{-11,1573,108},{-11,1574,106}},{{-11,1573,108},{-20,1523,103},{-11,1574,106}},{{-29,1472,96},{-46,1373,74},{-46,1373,72}},{{-46,1373,74},{-55,1324,60},{-46,1373,72}},{{-55,1324,60},{-64,1276,44},{-55,1325,58}},{{-64,1276,44},{-64,1276,42},{-55,1325,58}},{{-3,1625,108},{6,1676,106},{-2,1625,110}},{{-55,1324,60},{-55,1325,58},{-46,1373,72}},{{-11,1574,106},{-3,1625,108},{-2,1625,110}},{{-29,1472,96},{-46,1373,72},{-29,1473,94}},{{-20,1523,101},{-11,1574,106},{-20,1523,103}},{{-29,1472,96},{-29,1473,94},{-20,1523,103}},{{118,518,112},{117,564,83},{115,564,84}},{{117,516,109},{115,516,109},{114,562,81}},{{108,468,137},{109,469,139},{115,518,112}},{{-48,1374,71},{-57,1325,57},{-59,1325,58}},{{39,2147,-64},{39,2148,-62},{28,2202,-86}},{{108,468,137},{108,467,135},{94,415,157}},{{97,416,161},{111,468,138},{109,469,139}},{{14,236,191},{-23,168,185},{-22,168,184}},{{110,467,135},{108,467,135},{115,516,109}},{{8,807,-60},{6,806,-59},{30,767,-44}},{{45,301,186},{11,237,189},{12,237,191}},{{95,416,161},{109,469,139},{94,416,159}},{{109,469,139},{108,468,137},{94,416,159}},{{45,301,186},{12,237,191},{46,300,188}},{{95,416,161},{94,416,159},{74,360,177}},{{94,416,159},{72,360,176},{74,360,177}},{{72,360,176},{45,301,186},{74,360,177}},{{15,235,189},{48,299,186},{48,299,188}},{{12,237,191},{-25,169,185},{-23,168,185}},{{96,414,157},{94,415,157},{108,467,135}},{{-23,169,182},{-25,170,182},{12,237,187}},{{-25,169,185},{12,237,191},{11,237,189}},{{-31,1473,93},{-32,1473,94},{-24,1524,102}},{{76,359,177},{97,416,161},{95,416,161}},{{-50,1374,72},{-32,1473,94},{-31,1473,93}},{{107,606,51},{109,606,51},{116,562,80}},{{33,1832,79},{41,1884,62},{39,1885,63}},{{51,2043,-6},{52,2042,-7},{48,2095,-35}},{{52,2042,-7},{50,2095,-36},{48,2095,-35}},{{50,2095,-36},{43,2148,-63},{48,2095,-35}},{{-72,1228,27},{-64,1276,44},{-66,1276,45}},{{-66,1276,45},{-74,1228,28},{-72,1228,27}},{{-74,1228,28},{-81,1181,11},{-79,1182,10}},{{-81,1181,11},{-87,1092,-24},{-85,1092,-25}},{{-85,1051,-44},{-87,1094,-28},{-83,1050,-43}},{{-87,1094,-28},{-85,1093,-27},{-83,1050,-43}},{{-68,966,-66},{-70,966,-67},{-80,1008,-57}},{{-85,1051,-44},{-83,1050,-43},{-78,1008,-56}},{{-78,1008,-56},{-68,966,-66},{-80,1008,-57}},{{-81,1007,-54},{-72,965,-64},{-70,965,-63}},{{-81,1007,-54},{-70,965,-63},{-80,1007,-53}},{{-87,1092,-24},{-89,1092,-25},{-85,1049,-40}},{{-89,1092,-25},{-87,1049,-41},{-85,1049,-40}},{{-81,1007,-54},{-80,1007,-53},{-87,1049,-41}},{{-79,1182,8},{-79,1182,10},{-85,1092,-25}},{{-31,1473,93},{-29,1473,94},{-46,1373,72}}}
```

[image]

This is a polygon, my question is how can I get a curve function of this [curve]?

Maybe use Fit or FindFit?

Something like thinning a mesh into a curve.

A spiral line or a spline curve is OK.

[image]

In most cases, if the model is good, it's a Hexagon tube.

But in broken model, decimated by 3d software, some places of the tube is not so perfect.

I wish the method is capable to fit the cases above shown below pictures.

[image]
[image]
[image]

And if we get the line, when we do expand the line, the best result is the end of the segment is in the similar place of the origin.

**The background is I'm trying to replace the part of the tube with  rods or cylinders.**

Comment: You have a list of some hundred unsorted polygons, perhaps all triangles. What kind of curve you're looking for?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Maybe a spiral line, or a SplineCurve

Answer (score 0):

If a B-spline is adequate (as mentioned in your comment), then consider the following:

```
(* Get center of mass of each triangle *)
points = {Mean[#[[All, 1]]], Mean[#[[All, 2]]], Mean[#[[All, 3]]]} & /@ polygons;

(* Sort by the 2nd coordinate *)
points = Sort[points, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &];

(* Predict using B-splines *)
f21 = BSplineFunction[points[[All, {2, 1}]]];
f23 = BSplineFunction[points[[All, {2, 3}]]];

(* Show results *)
{ymin, ymax} = MinMax[points[[All, 2]]];
Show[ListPointPlot3D[points, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}, BoxRatios -> {1, 5, 1}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{f21[u][[2]], ymin + (ymax - ymin) u, f23[u][[2]]},
  {u, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Data and fit]